# How to process data in controller once received in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Assume I have a directive that contains a form where a user can enter in the name of a fruit.

1. I have a FruitFindController. User enters fruit name, "Apple", clicks a button which submits to controller.
2. Controller calls a service "GetFruitInfo(fruit)" and passes in "Apple" as parameter.
3. Once the information is received, it should call a method "addToListAndDoStuff()" in order to add the fruitinfo to the list.

My issue is, in my FruitFindController (assume fruitFinder is the service)...

```
 $scope.GetFruitInfo = function() {
                $scope.foundFruit = fruitFinder.GetFruitInfo($scope.fruitField);
                // should alert "Found Fruit" and call addToListAndDoStuff() method to add the foundFruit information to the list managed by another directive, "FruitList".
            }
```

What is the best way to "wait for the information is stored into $scope.foundFruit before doing any code below and popping up the alert box?

Comment: Is your fruitFinder returning a promise?

Comment: How is the `FruitFinder` service getting the fruit info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a promise. In your fruitFinder service, the GetFruitInfo method would look something like this..

```
function GetFruitInfo(fruit) {
  var delay = $q.defer();
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://myapi.com/getFruitInfo?fruit=' + fruit}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {   
      delay.resolve(data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      delay.reject(data);
    });
  return delay.promise;
}
```

This method returns a promise object that you can wait for it to resolve in your controller using the .then() method, like this..

```
 $scope.GetFruitInfo = function() {
   $scope.foundFruit = fruitFinder.GetFruitInfo($scope.fruitField).then(function(response) {
      alert('Found Fruit');
      addToListAndDoStuff(response);
    });
 }
```

Comment: How complicated is it if I need to make requests to say 100 urls for 100 fruits and "addToListAdnDoStuff"? Are the promises still relevant and the best way to handle this?

Comment: Promises are almost certainly the best way to handle any http request you are sending from your angular application. If you need to send request to different urls, you can just pass in the entire url to the GetFruitInfo(url) instead of hardcoding the url and passing in just the fruit